# Mahowald-Hopkins theorem

Tags: homology-cohomology, stable-homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, spectra

I am trying to recover fully a proof of a result which is attributed to M. Hopkins in the litterature, namely the following:

> Let $h:S^1\to BGL_1(\mathbb S_p)$ detect the element $1-p$, then the Thom spectrum of the induced map $f:\Omega^2S^3\to BGL_1(\mathbb S_p)$ is $H\mathbb F_p$

The proof I'm trying to focus on is that of Blumberg in [*THH of Thom spectra that are $E_\infty$-ring spectra*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0803). After showing that $Mf$ has a Thom class mod $p$, the author says that the argument is basically the same as the argument for $p=2$ where the sphere spectrum need not be localized.

The argument to which he is referring is that of Priddy in *$K(Z/2,0)$ as a Thom spectrum* : $H_*(\Omega^2 S^3;\mathbb F_2)\to \mathcal A_2^*$ is non trivial hence an isomorphism in degree $1$. Also, we know that $H_*(\Omega^2 S^3;\mathbb F_2)$ is generated by its degree one generator and the Dyer Lashof operation $Q_1$, as an algebra, and that the Thom isomorphisms preserve Dyer Lashof operations; and we know the action of $Q_1$ on the homology of the universal Thom spectrum $MO$ : $Q_1^{\circ n}p_1=p_n$ where $p_i$ is the primitive element in that dimension. So, the morphism of interest hits all the $p_i$s. Then by computing appropriate Kronecker brackets it is easy to show that the post composition with $H_*(MO;\mathbb F_2)\to \mathcal A_2^*$ is surjective hence an isomorphism.

I don't see how a proof for odd primes can be the same as that, because in our case the map does not factor (a priori) to an equivalent of $MO$ in the localized setting. Would it be that the homology of $MGL_1(\mathbb S^p)$ is well known as well as the action of Dyer Lashof operations on it ? So here is my main question : **what does Blumberg mean by "an analoguous argument" in his proof ?**

Otherwise, I can guess that there is a simpler proof in the case $p=2$ : as $f$ is an $E_2$ map, $Mf$ is an $E_2$-ring spectrum and it would not be surprising (although I don't know how to show it) if the map $Mf\to H\mathbb F_2$ representing the Thom class was an $E_2$-map. I know a proof of that in the $E_1$ case, where it is enough to work in the homotopy category. Would this be true for any connective $E_n$-ring spectrum ? Anyway, if it is true in our $E_2$ case, then it is just a matter of knowing the Dyer Lashof action on $H\mathbb F_2$, and the proof is then automatic. Also, the proof would be the same for odd primes.

Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] Indeed if $X$ is a connective $E_n$-ring spectrum, then the canonical map $E\to H(\pi_0(E))$ is an $E_n$-map because the two maps $$E_n(k)_+\wedge_{\mathfrak S_n} E^{(k)}\to\cdots\to H(\pi_0(E))$$ of interest both induce the multiplication map $\pi_0(E)^r\to\pi_0(E)$. So if I'm not mistaken the proof can be finished just by looking at the Dyer Lashof operations on $H\mathbb F_p$ (by using this fact for $E:=Mf\wedge H\mathbb F_p)$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but have you seen the proof of theorem 5.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7988 ? they do seem to mention that we know a whole lot about Dyer-Lashof operations in this type of scenario. As for your edit, note that $\pi_0: Sp_{\geq 0}\to Ab$ is symmetric monoidal, and so its right adjoint $H$ is also lax symmetric monoidal, which makes the unit transformation $id \to H\pi_0$ a lax symmetric monoidal transformation; in particular when $X$ is $E_n$, so is $H\pi_0$, and the map is $E_n$ too

Comment: Yes, but to use Dyer Lashof operations to conclude, we want the map $Mf\to H\mathbb F_p$ to be compatible with them, which lead me to my last question and my edit. Indeed once we know this fact, the Dyer Lashof algebra structure on $\mathcal A_p^*$ concludes the proof I think. Also I'm ok with your nice categorical argument, thank you. However to really conclude I guess you have to invoke the uniqueness of the $E_n$ structure on $H\pi_0(E)$, which will be proven by arguments like that of the edit right ?

Comment: I'm assuming your $E$ here is $Mf$, and so $H\pi_0(E)\simeq \mathbb F_p$ as spectra, and you would want it to be true as $E_n$-rings, is that it ? Then indeed, you can invoke that, or in that case, you can do better : the $E_n$ structure on $Mf$ induces an $E_n$-structure on $\pi_0(Mf)\cong \mathbb F_p$, which is, this time, obviously unique, and so the one you get on $H\pi_0$ is also the correct one - so you don't need anything fancy here.

Comment: I was taking $E=Mf\wedge H\mathbb F_p$ but taking $Mf$ happens to be equivalent. I had understood your argument indeed, the only thing is the unicity of the structure on $HR$ which doesn't seem more evident to me when we take $R=\mathbb F_p$ than for general $R$. Do you have a direct abstract argument in the particular case of $\mathbb F_p$ ?

Comment: Notice I said the unicity of the structure on $\mathbb F_p$, not $H\mathbb F_p$ (a distinction I rarely make :) but here it's relevant): since you're going through $\pi_0$, you end up in a discrete world, where $\mathbb F_p$ has only one commutative algebra structure (and so, $E_n$ for all $n$, as $Alg_{E_n}(discrete rings)= Alg_{Com}(discrete rings)$ for $n\geq 2$)